# transferring data to new Macbook Pro

Tags: data-transfer, migration, migration-assistant

I just got a new Macbook Pro, and even though I have been using Time Machine and I could use the Migration Assistant, I've accumulated so many files throughout the years that I thought it would be great to start fresh and transfer only what I think is important. Of course transferring my personal files is straightforward, as well with Notes, Calendars, Contacts, Reminders, Safari, KeyChain, etc. where iCloud makes it really easy. But then there are is the data of some applications that it's very hard:

- Messages (I can't seem to get it right, and I've seen [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5852849))
- Stickies
- Photos
- iTunes
- etc.?

Comment: iTunes: Open Finder, then in the menu bar, click view>Go After a small dialogue window shows, enter the following directory: /Users/username/Music    right click on the iTunes Folder, copy it to an external disk (or transfer it via AFP or with another Application) then put it back into the other mac with the same username and file structure as the old one.

Comment: Photos… ~/Pictures move the Photos [or iPhoto] Library file

Answer (score -3):

this article should be useful to you

http://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/setting-up-a-new-mac-should-you-migrate-or-do-a-clean-installation/